# Update end date by adding duration to start date in derby database

Tags: derby

I created table using Derby database.

```
CREATE TABLE PROJECT
(PID  INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
PSDATE DATE,
PDURATION INTEGER,
PEDATE DATE,
PRIMARY KEY (PID)
);
```

I attempted to update end date in this project table, adding duration to start date.

```
UPDATE PROJECT
SET PEDATE = ADD_MONTHS (PROJECT.PSDATE, PROJECT.PDURATION)
WHERE PID = PROJECT.PID;
```

But I am getting below error

```
"[Exception, Error code 30,000, SQLState 42Y03] 'ADD_MONTHS' is not recognized as a function or 
 procedure.
 Line 1, column 1"
```

Later I tried with below code

```
select {fn TIMESTAMPADD(SQL_TSI_DAY, +pduration, psdate)}
from name.PROJECT
where pid = project.PID
```

Can I use TIMESTAMPADD function to update project table in Derby database?
Thanks in advance to help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE PROJECT 
SET PEDATE = DATE( {fn TIMESTAMPADD(SQL_TSI_MONTH, PDURATION, PSDATE)} );
```

This query (provided by [Akina](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/150107/akina)) updates my end date when adding duration to start date.